# Download Income Statement from web page using BeautifulSoup and convert to Pandas dataframe?

Tags: html, pandas, dataframe, html-table, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab the Income Statement table OF McDonald's Corporation (MCD) "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MCD/financials?p=MCD". I used beaufiful soup. The html is downloaded, but there seems no typical "tr", "td" tag for the income statement table. How to convert the income statement table into df dataframe?

my codes:

```
url="https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MCD/financials?p=MCD"
result = requests.get(url)
result.raise_for_status()
result.encoding = "utf-8"


src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
print(soup)

array = []
for tr_tag in soup.find_all('tr'):
    b_tag = tr_tag.find_all('td')
    array.append(b_tag)
print(array)
```

Comment: It's possible to get the data from each row in the table separately into python rows, but the problem is that the rows will be of unequal length because some of them are collapsible (like operating expenses) and some items are missing where there should have been zeros (like R&D). So you will have to do some list and string manipulation to whip these rows into a shape suitable for pandas. If you are interested, I can post an answer with the 1st step, but for the 2nd you'll be on your own...

Comment: Yes, please send me step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"Download Income Statement from web page using BeautifulSoup..."***

First, you say `soup.find_all('tr')`; however, there are no `tr` tags in the income statements table. On the website, each row has a `div` tag which then has a specific `class`. Specifying the `class` can really help you tell the program exactly what you want from the website. I used the `div class` of "D(tbr) fi-row Bgc($hoverBgColor):h" because it is consistent across each row of the table. You can then use the `text` function to get the raw text from the website instead of the `HTML`.

```
url="https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MCD/financials?p=MCD"
result = requests.get(url)
result.raise_for_status()
result.encoding = "utf-8"

src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

rows = []
for i in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'D(tbr) fi-row Bgc($hoverBgColor):h'}):
    row = i.text
    rows.append(row)

print(rows)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The downloaded row is like "Diluted-7.546.375.44". How to also download the column divider do the result will be like "Diluted - 7.54 6.37 5.44"?

Comment: You will most likely have to parse the output (Diluted-7.546.375.44) using indexing. For example, `string = "Diluted-7.546.375.44"`. You can use indexing to get certain elements of the string: `string[0:7]` will return `"Diluted"`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, here's your step 1:

```
targets = soup.find("div",{'data-reactid':'41'})
rows = []
for target in targets:
    data = target.find_all('span')
    row = []
    for d in data:
        row.append(d.text)
    rows.append(row)
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

output:

```
['Total Revenue', '21,076,500', '21,025,200', '22,820,400', '24,621,900']
['Cost of Revenue', '9,961,200', '10,239,200', '12,199,600', '14,417,200']
['Gross Profit', '11,115,300', '10,786,000', '10,620,800', '10,204,700']
['Operating Expenses', 'Research Development', 'Selling General and Administrative', '2,229,400', '2,200,200', '2,231,300', '2,384,500', 'Total Operating Expenses', '2,045,500', '2,200,200', '2,231,300', '2,384,500']
```

etc.